# Angular app with Laravel backend as API RESTful Auth issues

Tags: angular, laravel, rest, api, authentication

I'm having problems with authenticating users who are in session and CORS. Clearly something I do not understand or I have not read. 
Should I use Passport on the Laravel side? And on the side of Angular?

I need some kind of basic authentication. I am having constant blockages by cors, for not having the "Authorization header", etc.

What official guide or article should I read?
PS: I already readed the OAuth RFC but I do not understand how Angular and Laravel implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using Passport. It manages all almost automatically using OAuth2. Its amazing. Passport has a full documentation inside Laravel oficial documentation.

You issue about authorization header is due to obviously that header. You will have to append your 'session' Bearer token inside it.

You can find almost all details step by step here:
[Tutorial Api Laravel - Angular 4](http://cristianoventura.com.br/2017/08/restful-api-with-laravel-and-angular-4/)

Good look!